# Stream node requests to the cloud with file metadata

Tags: node.js, express, stream, koa2, node-streams

Im using koa in order to build a web app, and I want to allow users to upload files to it. The files need to be streamed to the cloud, but I would like to avoid saving the file locally.

The problem is that I need some file metadata before I pipe the upload stream to the writeable stream. I want to have the mime-type and optionally attach other data like the original file name etc.

I tried sending the binary data with the request's "content-type" header set to the file's type, but I would like the request to have the content type `application/octet-stream` so I can know in the back-end how to handle the request.

I read somewhere that the better option would be to use `multipart/form-data` but I'm not sure how to structure the request, and how to parse the metadata in order to notify the cloud before I pipe to its write stream.

Here is the code im currently using. Basically, it just pipes the request as is, and I use the request header to know the type of the file:

```
module.exports = async ctx => {
  // Generate a random id that will be part of the filename.
  const id = pushid();
  // Get the content type from the header.
  const contentType = ctx.header['content-type'];
  // Get the extension for the file from the content type
  const ext = contentType.split('/').pop();

  // This is the configuration for the upload stream to the cloud.
  const uploadConfig = {
    // I must specify a content type, or know the file extension.
    contentType

    // there is some other stuff here but its not relevant.
  };

  // Create a upload stream for the cloud storage.
  const uploadStream = bucket
    .file(`assets/${id}/original.${ext}`)
    .createWriteStream(uploadConfig);

  // Here is what took me hours to get to work... dev life is hard
  ctx.req.pipe(uploadStream);

  // return a promise so Koa doesn't shut down the request before its finished uploading.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    uploadStream.on('finish', resolve).on('error', reject)
  );
};
```

**Please assume I don't know much about the uploading protocols and managing streams.**

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a lot of searching I found out that there is a parser that works with streams called `busboy`. It is pretty easy to use, but before jumping into the code I highly suggest everyone dealing with `multipart/form-data` requests to [read this article](http://derpturkey.com/node-multipart-form-data-explained/).

Here is how I solved it:

```
const Busboy = require('busboy');

module.exports = async ctx => {
  // Init busboy with the headers of the "raw" request.
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: ctx.req.headers });

    busboy.on('file', (fieldname, stream, filename, encoding, contentType) => {
        const id = pushid();
        const ext = path.extname(filename);
        const uploadStream = bucket
            .file(`assets/${id}/original${ext}`)
            .createWriteStream({
                contentType,
                resumable: false,
                metadata: {
                    cacheControl: 'public, max-age=3600'
                }
            });

        stream.pipe(uploadStream);
    });

  // Pipe the request to busboy.
    ctx.req.pipe(busboy);

  // return a promise that resolves to whatever you want
    ctx.body = await new Promise(resolve => {
        busboy.on('finish', () => {
            resolve('done');
        });
    });
};
```